# Compare two lists to make them equal in elements

Tags: c#, list, compare

I have two lists named List1 & List2.

Now say List1 & List2 has 5 elements {a,b,c,d,e}. Now if I remove {b,c} from List1 and add {f,g,h} to List1, how can i make List2 Equal(by doing add & remove operation on it.).

Comment: Why not `List2 = List1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "(by doing add & remove operation on it.)"

Why this constraint?
The easiest, most reliable and probably the fastest way:

```
List2 = List1.ToList();
```

But if you really want it:

```
List2.RemoveRange(List2.Except(List1));  // You may have to write RemoveRange()
List2.AddRange(List1.Except(List2));
```

Comment: Latter you need a loop to remove :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - why? I don't see that. But I fixed the Add/Remove part, initially I had it wrong.

Comment: @Henk - Since references are not same for `List1` and `List2`. So for further updates to `List1` won't be reflected to `List2`.

Comment: I hope you know `Except` returns a sequence whereas Remove/Add needs an element as parameter

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - right, consider this pseudo-code. I'll edit with `AddRange()`

Comment: @RohitVats - Yes, but keeping them synced is not part of the requirements. If it was, your `List2 = List1` would be best, but that is a different situation.

Comment: `RemoveRange` ? There is no overload that takes `IEnumerable` which returns `Except`.

Comment: Right, see the comment. You can easily write en extension method.

Answer (score 1):

Let the List2 be just a reference of List1, for example:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
List<string> list2 = list1;
```

Modifying the list1 will affect the list2 as well

Answer (score 0):

The @Henk Holterman suggests the right way(on the first part of the answer), but if you want exactly what you mentioned in OP then you can use this

```
list2.RemoveAll(l => !list1.Contains(l));
list2.AddRange(list1.Except(list2));
```